# Easiest way to find when a specific change occured in git

Tags: git

Let's say I have a file, say `foo.py`. Browsing the code, some changed occured and I would need to know when that specific change was made. For instance:

```
def bar():
   answer = 43
   return f"The answer is:{answer}"
```

The answer obviously being 42, and there not having a comment, I need to find out when in the commit history that line was changed to understand if it is legit or not.

Any good, programmatic way to do this? Or is just browsing the commit history the way to do it?

Comment: IDE's with GIT integration like Visual Studio Code, PHPStorm, etc. can show you that easily for every line (it seems +- like a placeholder in each line.) Here is an example: https://gyazo.com/11aaf5137e45975ef269fd1992425404

Comment: @PedroRodrigues thanks (I'm with intellij stuff). I still prefer cmd lines for stuff like git to be honest - just that once I know it, I'm not dependent on my dev env (or need to figure out how to do the same thing in yet another tool).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use git annotate:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-annotate

so

```
git annotate -L <line number start, line number end> <file>
```

or specifically

```
git annotate -L 4,-2 foo.py
```

or even

```
git annotate foo.py
```

Also there are tons of tools depending on your IDE that will do this without running to the command line.  [Git lens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) is one of many for VSCode: .

Comment: No spaces between -L argument - otherwise throws errors. Could you edit? But yes pretty what I had in mind. Much prefer to use git annotate from cmd line than some IDE personally, but thanks for mentioning the options (issue with IDE is that if for whatever reason I want to that in a place where I'm not using that idea, I have to figure it  out again...).Thanks

Comment: Good catch!  Edited.